# Plain JS Ajax Upload Progress Event Not Working

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I am trying to use object-oriented code to handle an AJAX upload. When I run the code, it sees the file, creates the XMLHttpRequest object, but I cannot seem to get the progress event to fire. The full source of my code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/89QawbS6

Here is a snippet:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", MyObj.trackProgress, false);

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
...
```

Then in that same object, different method:

```
trackProgress: function (event) {
    console.log(event);

    // stuff that should calculate percent
}
```

But that console.log(event) never fires.

Please note: I know jQuery is great, and there are a dozen awesome upload plugins that I could just use instead. I am not doing this for a class or homework, I just want to understand the process better myself. So offering a jQuery plugin as an answer is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to make myself less dependent on jQuery.

Comment: Progress event fires for me using your code. What browser are you testing this in? Progress event is not supported by all versions. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: @peterfoldi: Firefox 25.

Comment: Doesn't work in FF indeed. Works in Chrome.

Comment: Works. Try to upload big files. I don't know what's the min limit. I tested with a 900kbfile and it fired once, probably would fire more times if not running on localhost. But MDN says it's fired "zero or more times". So zero times fire is still ok and probably FF does that when the file is small.

Comment: And it fired several times with an 57mb file (the previous test was 900kb only). I think your code is ok.

Comment: I tried a 20MB+ file, and I still get the same issue, I never see the event fire in my console at all. I have not tried it in Chrome or another browser, but I will do that. I still need to solve it for Firefox.

Comment: This FF bug might be related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=908375 It's reported on MacOSX and another similar bug on Linux. I don't know if that matters but I tested on Windows. I still believe that your code is fine.

Comment: I am running on Linux, so it may just be that. Exasperating that this is the problem (I ran the test pages provided in the comments, and it failed on each one but ran mostly fine in chromium).

@peterfoldi: please link that as answer so I can reward you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This FF bug might](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=908375) be the reason for your issue. It's reported on MacOSX and another similar bug on Linux. I don't know if that matters but I tested on Windows. I still believe that your code is fine.